# Help with an integral

Tags: symbolic, calculus-and-analysis

I want to know if the following integral can be evaluated in Mathematica:

$$ g(t)= c\int_{0}^{1-t} t^{m-1}\left[(u+t)^{m}-u^{m}\right]^{n-2}(u+t)^{m-1} d u$$ where $$ c= m^2n(n-1)$$

```
g[u_] = ct^(m - 1)((u + t)^m - u^m)^(n - 2)(u + t)^(m - 1)
Integrate[g[u], {u, 0, 1 - t},Assumptions->{m>0,n>0}]
```

Could somebody kindly paste it in Mathematica under the assumptions  $m,n \in \mathbb{N},$ the set of natural numbers? I would also like to know if we can evaluate it in Mathematica for the case when $m$ and $n$ approach infinity and the numerical evaluation of the integral for given $m$ and  $n$. Right now I do not have access to Mathematica. I would be highly grateful for any help.

Comment: You have many syntactic errors.

Comment: @David G.Stork ,now I have written the integral in mathematical form as well.kindly point out the syntactic errors

Comment: Wrong:  `g[u] =`.  Right:  `g[u_] := `.  Wrong:  `t^{m - 1}`.  Right:  `t^(m-1)`.  Wrong: `[(u + t)^{m} - u^{m}`.  Right:  `(u+t)^m - u^m]^(n - 2)`.  Wrong: 
 `(u + t)^{m - 1}`.  Right:  `(u+t)^(m-1)`.  Also:  don't include useless, irrelevant constant factor.  Waste of time.

Comment: `c = m^2*n*(n - 1);
c*Integrate[
  t^(m - 1)*((u + t)^m - u^m)^(n - 2)*(u + t)^(m - 1), {u, 0, 1 - t}]`

Comment: Maybe try Wolfram alpha.

Comment: Use `((u + t)^m - u^m)` instead of `[(u + t)^m - u^m]` and remove 'dots' from your code. Thus people can copy and paste your code in Mathematica and would help you with a possible solution.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @bbgodfrey ,thank you a lot for your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 4):

Let us focus on the underlying indefinite integral,

```
Integrate[((u + t)^m - u^m)^(n - 2)*(u + t)^(m - 1), u, 
    Assumptions -> (n | m) ∈ Integers && n > 1]
```

Unfortunately, it returns unevaluated.  In contrast, `Integrate` returns a result for any `n` satisfying the assumptions.  For instance,

```
With[{n = 3}, Integrate[((u + t)^m - u^m)^(n - 2)*(u + t)^(m - 1), u]]
(* (t + u)^(2 m)/(2 m) - (u^(1 + m) (t + u)^m (1 + u/t)^-m 
   Hypergeometric2F1[1 - m, 1 + m, 2 + m, -(u/t)])/((1 + m) t) *)
```

To seek a pattern for the solution, try

```
Table[Simplify[Integrate[((u + t)^m - u^m)^(n - 2)*(u + t)^(m - 1), u],
    m ∈ Integers], {n, 2, 10}]
```

from which the general solution easily can be identified.

```
f[n_?IntegerQ] := (t + u)^((n - 1) m)/((n - 1) m) +  
    Sum[(-1)^nn Binomial[n - 2, nn] t^((n - nn - 1) m) u^(1 + nn m) Hypergeometric2F1[
    1 - (n - nn - 1) m, 1 + nn m, 2 + nn m, -u/t]/((1 + nn m ) t), {nn, 1, n}]
```

This result can be tested by

```
Table[Simplify[Integrate[((u + t)^m - u^m)^(n - 2)*(u + t)^(m - 1), u] == f[n], 
    m ∈ Integers], {n, 2, 10}]
(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

after which the multiplier `c t^(m - 1)` and the limits of integration can be applied.